# Spring Security ignoring roles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this controller:

```
@RestController
public class NumbersController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ONE')")
    @GetMapping("/one")
    private String one(){
        return "This is one.";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_TWO')")
    @GetMapping("/two")
    private String two(){
        return "This is two.";
    }
}
```

And this security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(encoder.encode("password")).roles("ONE");
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user2").password(encoder.encode("password2")).roles("TWO");
    }

}
```

And while running both of my users can access both of the resources. What I want is only for `user` to be able to access `/one` and only for `user2` to access `/two`.
I also tried using `@Secured("ONE")` with the same result.

Console output:

```
2021-01-14 16:10:20.026  INFO 4376 --- [           main] security.security.SecurityApplication    : Starting SecurityApplication on Ivan-PC with PID 4376 (D:\Z\security\target\classes started by Ivan in D:\Z\security)
2021-01-14 16:10:20.041  INFO 4376 --- [           main] security.security.SecurityApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-14 16:10:24.363  INFO 4376 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-01-14 16:10:24.378  INFO 4376 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-14 16:10:24.378  INFO 4376 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-14 16:10:24.565  INFO 4376 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-14 16:10:24.565  INFO 4376 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4321 ms
2021-01-14 16:10:25.221  INFO 4376 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-14 16:10:25.860  INFO 4376 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@57a48985, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@17740dae, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@14bf57b2, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@48535004, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3cee53dc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@67440de6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@35835e65, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@1ab6718, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@7ce7e83c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@345cf395, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7144655b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3910fe11, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@14379273, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@cfbc8e8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@49293b43]
2021-01-14 16:10:25.969  INFO 4376 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-14 16:10:25.985  INFO 4376 --- [           main] security.security.SecurityApplication    : Started SecurityApplication in 6.771 seconds (JVM running for 8.031)
2021-01-14 16:10:29.847  INFO 4376 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-01-14 16:10:29.848  INFO 4376 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-01-14 16:10:29.870  INFO 4376 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 22 ms
```

The requests are made with Postman to `http://localhost:8080/two` and using the authorization fields.

Comment: several things, post your full debug logs, also post how you are doing calls. Method security is used only for when calling methods and is using AOP security, if you are doing http rest calls you need to configure `HttpSecurity`. Vote to close too little debugging information.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc

Comment: Configuring `HttpSecurity` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this if it helps,

We can configure multiple HttpSecurity instances just as we can have multiple  blocks. The key is to extend the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter multiple times. For example, the following is an example of having a different configuration for URL’s that start with /api/.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    @Bean                                                             
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        // ensure the passwords are encoded properly
        UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(users.username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(users.username("admin").password("password").roles("USER","ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }
@Configuration
@Order(1)                                                        
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")                               
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    }
}

@Configuration                                                   
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults());
    }
}
}
```

Configure Authentication as normal
Create an instance of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that contains @Order to specify which WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should be considered first.
The http.antMatcher states that this HttpSecurity will only be applicable to URLs that start with /api/
Create another instance of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
If the URL does not start with /api/ this configuration will be used.
This configuration is considered after ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter since it has an @Order value after 1 (no @Order defaults to last).

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't using HttpSecurity, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this in your `SecurityConfig` class

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
      prePostEnabled = true,  
      jsr250Enabled = true)
```

- The prePostEnabled property enables Spring Security pre/post annotations
- The jsr250Enabled property allows us to use the @RoleAllowed annotation

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: This has worked for me. Can you please cross check once again!

Comment: Yep, still nothing. I feel it has something to do with the assignment of roles, I'm going to check that out. Thanks for the help.